# Render Html in XAML + windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a proprety in my model that contain HTML ex:

```
public class watch
{
public string description=<div>hello<br/> world</div>
}
```

I need in the view in xaml code to bind this description with a composant.
which composant should i use (RichTextblock or ...) to render this html??
if i use `<textblock text={binding="descrption"}/>` the html tags still visible, i need to return to ligne and do not show html tags

Any ideas please??

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The WebView control gives us a way to host HTML data within our app.
>   But if we look at its Source property, we see that it takes the Uri of
>   the web page to display. Our HTML data is just a string of HTML. It
>   doesn't have a Uri that we can bind to the Source property. Luckily,
>   there is a NavigateToString method that we can pass our string of HTML
>   to.

So do:

```
ContentView.NavigateToString(w.description);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) control. There's a `NavigateToString` method that may help.

Answer (score 0):

There´s another approach, that is building the parts (blocks) of a XAML `RichTextBlock` from an Html text. It involves more work than a WebView and it´s hard to support all tags, but if you just need a limited subset of html tags and you want more formatting control it´s very handy. Take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/xleon/XAMLHtml)

You basically bind your description property:

```
<RichTextBlock html:Properties.Html="{Binding description}"/>
```

Here´s an example:

[image]